# Имя ему или имя его?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Имя ему Даниил" или "Имя его Даниил"?

Answer (score 1):

"Имя ему Даниил" - походит на пояснение с возвышенными тонами, мол: "Знаешь, как имя этого героя? Имя ему - Даниил!" 
"Имя его Даниил" - походит на тон знатока к невежде, мол: "Правильно не "Дамил", а "Даниил".